# How to override the css in jqcloud?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to display three different word list in a same word cloud using jqcloud in such a way that words from same list should displayed in same color and the color for each list should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have two arrays;

```
 var word_list1 = new Array(
        {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4},
        {text: "Sit", weight: 8},
        {text: "Amet", weight: 6.2}};
 var word_list2 = new Array(
        {text: "Consectetur", weight: 5},
        {text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5},
        {text: "Elit", weight: 5},
        {text: "Nam et", weight: 5},
        {text: "Leo", weight: 4}};
```

You can add color attribute like;

```
for (var i = 0; i < word_list1.length; i++) {
    word_list1[i].color = "green";      //i.e. {text: "Leo", weight: 4, color:"green"}};
}       

for (var i = 0; i < word_list2.length; i++) {
    word_list2[i].color = "red";
}
```

finally

```
$("#wordcloud").jQCloud(word_list1.concat(word_list2.concat));
```

Comment: This is not working as Jqcloud does not accept any color attribute. I solve the problem. Please find the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem. here is the steps:

1. first create two css class with color attribute as you want. like:

   ```
   .customclass{color:red}
   ```

   `.customclass2{color:green}`
2. Then in your word array add an extra element `html` and assign the css class to it

   `var word_list1 = new Array({text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4, html:{class:'customclass'}},{text: "Sit", weight: 8,html{class:'customclass'}},{text: "Amet", weight:6.2,html{class:'customclass'}});
   var word_list2 = new Array({text: "Consectetur", weight: 5, html:{class:'customclass2'}},{text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5,html{class:'customclass2'}},{text: "Elit", weight: 5, html:{class:'customclass2'}},{text: "Nam et", weight: 5, html:{class:'customclass2'}},{text: "Leo", weight: 4,html:{class:'customclass2'}});`
3. Then render the cloud like this
   `$("#demo").jQCloud(word_list1.concat(word_list2.concat));`